# How do I properly enable ANSI escape sequences in cgdb?

Tags: cgdb

I am using CGDB version 0.6.7 (latest available from apt) on WSL2. Colors are showing properly in the code window, but I see sequences like `[34m` in the lower window. See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of cgdb]

The only way I have found to get rid of these is by using the command `set style enabled off`. However, it would be nicer if it just worked instead of having to disable the feature altogether. How can I set this up so that the escape sequences work properly in the lower window?